# angular 4 animation bug

Tags: angular, animation

I have got divA and divB. divB is inside of divA just like in my template code:

```
<div class="divA" *ngIf="state=='active'">
  <div class="divB"
    [@selectState]="state" 
  ></div>
</div>
```

I have got an animation for them in the component. (It's a simple slide down, slide up animation when state is active/inactive.)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-divs',
  templateUrl: './divs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./divs.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('selectState', [
      state('inactive', style({
        height: '0rem'
      })),
      state('active', style({
        height: '*'
      })),
      transition('inactive => active', animate('300ms ease-in')),
      transition('active => inactive', animate('300ms ease-out'))
    ])
  ]
})
```

This should create divA and slide down divB when state='active'. The result: divA is created and slide animation is skipped. My question is how could I fix this situation in my code? I tried to create divA with other variable (not with state) but the result was the same.

Thanks for your answers and time!

Answer (score 0):

try using `hidden` instead of `*ngIf`. When the component is created, it's created with the active state, so there is no transition between the two states.

```
<div class="divA" [hidden]="state!='active'">
  <div class="divB"
    [@selectState]="state" 
  ></div>
</div>
```

**Update**

if you must use `*ngIf`, use you can use `setTimeout` to overcome this. You can declare another variable for the `selectState` and then make this variable `"inactive"` with `setTimeout`. Something like this,

```
<div class="divA" [hidden]="state!='active'">
  <div class="divB" [@selectState]="otherState" 
  ></div>
</div>
```

TS :

```
this.state = 'active';
this.otherState = 'inactive'
setTimeout(() => this.otherState = 'active', 100);
```

Comment: First of all thanks your answer but it does not solves my problem. The ngIf is important part there for me :S (Idk if I should use jQuery for workaround)

Comment: @BálintRéthy, I update the answer to offer a workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use ChangeDetector, import it in constructor of that component like:

```
private chRef: ChangeDetector
```

and later use:

```
chRef.detectChanges();
```

It will detect ngIf changes to the dom